# Constants for infinity

Tags: python

Are there constants for infinity in python?

The only way I found was to parse the values from a string.

```
INF = float("inf")
NINF = float("-inf")
```

Comment: Looks like this is as close as it came to implementation (as of 2008): http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Even [`fpconst`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fpconst) generates them by unpacking the IEEE 754 bit sequences.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
inf = 1e3000
ninf = -1e3000
```

Comment: You don't need the calls to `float` there.

Comment: These aren't actually constants per se though. It's just the compiler giving up on trying to find a valid IEEE 754 representation.